# custom listview inside custom dialog

Tags: android

i want to ask something about listview and dialog

i have a dialog that show a custom layout with edit text, text view, and listview

the problems is, when the dialog loaded up, everthings inside this dialog work fine to be handled by clicklistener, but...

the listview not responding to onitemclicklistener...

i`ve search about this but there`s no solution for my problems... hope you can help me figure it out... 
so many thanks ^^

**here my code**

```
li            = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        someLayout    = (LinearLayout)li.inflate(R.layout.d_bon_rokok_add_main, null);

        lblDate       = (TextView)someLayout.findViewById(R.id.d_bonRokokAddMain_lblTgl);
        txtStartDate  = (EditText)someLayout.findViewById(R.id.d_bonRokokAddMain_txtStartDate);
        lblTo         = (TextView)someLayout.findViewById(R.id.d_bonRokokAddMain_lblTo);
        txtEndDate    = (EditText)someLayout.findViewById(R.id.d_bonRokokAddMain_txtEndDate);
        btnSearch     = (Button)someLayout.findViewById(R.id.d_bonRokokAddMain_btnSearch);
        ll_add        = (LinearLayout)someLayout.findViewById(R.id.d_bonRokokAddMain_llBottom);
        btnSave_add   = (Button)someLayout.findViewById(R.id.d_bonRokokAddMain_btnNext);
        btnCancel_add = (Button)someLayout.findViewById(R.id.d_bonRokokAddMain_btnCancel);
        lvDialog = (ListView)someLayout.findViewById(R.id.d_bonRokokAddMain_lvDialog);

        initializeDate_d();

        cbRokokAdd      = (CheckBox)someLayout.findViewById(R.id.d_bonRokokAddMain_cbNewForm);
        cbHeaderDialog  = (CheckBox)someLayout.findViewById(R.id.d_bonRokokAddMain_cbHeader);

        cbRokokAdd.setChecked(true);

        hideWidget();

        cbRokokAdd.setOnCheckedChangeListener(switchControl);
        txtStartDate.setOnClickListener(dialogStartDate);
        txtStartDate.setKeyListener(null);
        txtEndDate.setOnClickListener(dialogEndDate);
        txtEndDate.setKeyListener(null);


        dialogItemList = login.dbResetData.GetSalesPlan();
        final bonrokok_salesplan_adapter dialogAdapter = new bonrokok_salesplan_adapter(this, dialogItemList);
        lvDialog.setAdapter(dialogAdapter);

        cbHeaderDialog.setOnCheckedChangeListener(cbHeaderControl);

        lvDialog.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                Log.d("Result", "Hey it`s work!!!");

            }
        });

        alert = new Dialog(this);
        alert.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        btnSave_add.setOnClickListener(dialogYes);
        btnCancel_add.setOnClickListener(dialogNo);
        alert.setContentView(someLayout);

        alert.getWindow().getAttributes().width = LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT;
        alert.getWindow().getAttributes().height = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        alert.show();
```

Comment: Not responding means? Is there any crash?

Comment: Post code for custom dialog

Comment: can you show us the listview adapter ?